# Python MySQL csvについての質問です。

Tags: python, mysql, csv

Python MySQL csv
についての質問です。
現在センサの勉強を行っており、サーバにセンサデータを送って処理をするということをやって勉強しています。
プログラムを書いたのですが、エラー出てわからないので質問させていただきました。

プログラムの内容としてcsvファイルに書き込まれているデータの一番最初の列がIDでそのIDを取り出して、
その取り出したIDからデータベースにあるメールアドレスを特定してｂに代入、printで表示するものです。
おそらくエラーを読む限り、変数の型がちがうのではないかと思っているのですが、プログラムの書き方がわかりません。

教えていただけると助かります。

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

MySQL接続
cur = cnt.cursor()

f=open('data2.csv','r')
for line in f:
    a=line.split(',')[0]
    cur.execute('SELECT ADDRESS FROM user WHERE ID=%d',int(a))
    b=cur.fetchone()
    print (b)

cur.close
cnt.close
f.close()
```

data2.csv (一番最初の列がID)

```
1111,4686
2222,4846
```

データベース

```
ID    MAIL
1111 sample@gmail.com
2222 sample@gmail.com
```

実行結果エラー

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".py", line 11, in <module>
cur.execute('SELECT ADDRESS FROM user WHERE ID=%d',int(a))
File "/root/.pyev/versions/anaconda3.1/lib/python3.6/site-pakages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 234, in execute
args = tuple(map(db.literal, args))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `%d`となっているところを`?`にして、`int(a)`を`(int(a), )`に直す必要がありそうですね。

Comment: あと`commit`が呼ばれていないので、dbが更新されないかも。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/103235